# How to prove $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_{p^k}): \mathbb Q] = (p-1)*p^{k-1}$?

Tags: extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I want to prove that $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_{p^k}): \mathbb Q] = (p-1)*p^{k-1}$ where $\zeta_p = \exp\left (\frac {2 \pi i} p\right )$. I have done this for $k = 2$ by looking at $m(x) = \frac{X^p-1}{X-1}$ and $n(x) = m(x^p)$ which are irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb Q$. This gives the degree for $ k=1$ and $k=2$. Can I somehow prove my assertion by induction of must I proceed like $n'(x) := m(x^{p^2})$ etc.  ?

Comment: Do you know what the cyclotomic polynomial is? Can you prove it is irreducible over $\,\Bbb Q[x]\;$ ?

Comment: Nope. I just know that my polynomials are special cases of those but I can not prove that those are in general irreducible. Is there a way which is more straigt forward ?

Comment: Well, read this: http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lehigh.edu%2F~shw2%2Fpreprints%2Fseveral_proofs-newnew.pdf&ei=o4DBUb6bFoXxsgaWy4CwAg&usg=AFQjCNFuKk0ngzrDrP8iqY5eTpMgg09NkQ&sig2=Tc-VAraI5P3qp3UxMenpjQ&bvm=bv.47883778,d.Yms